# Django: how to use upload_to property of an ImageField

Tags: python, django, file-upload, dry

I'm writing a large application with image uploads.

Here is my model:

```
class GallryImage(models.Model):
    # ...
    image   = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to='gallery', height_field='width', width_field='height')
    width   = models.IntegerField()
    height  = models.IntegerField()
    # ...
```

And here is how I handle the upload:

```
image_name = 'image.png';
destination = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/gallery/' + image_name, 'wb+')
for chunk in f.chunks():
    destination.write(chunk)
destination.close()
```

This code, kind of, violates the DRY principle - the path `gallery` is repeated twice.

**Question:** how do I reuse path that I have specified in my model (`upload_to='gallery'`), so that I would not have to repeat in upload handler?

I am using python 2.6 and Django 1.3 beta.

Thank you!

**Solution based on Paulo's answer**

When instance of a model is saved, the file is uploaded automatically, so all I have to do is this:

```
def add(request):
    from forms import ImageAddForm
    form = ImageAddForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = GalleryImage(
                image   = form.cleaned_data['image']
            )
            image.save() # file is uploaded to upload_to dir!
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('image_add') + '?image_added=')
    else:
        form = ImageAddForm()

    return render_to_response('gallery/add.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Why are you saving the image by hand? The forms framework should take care of this for you.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine, If you post an example (or a link to it) as an answer I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [forms framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) should take care of this for you. No need to save the files by hand unless you want to store them in some container other than your filesystem.

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GallryImage
...
# Sample view
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: And the handle_uploaded_file() is...? If you read documentation further, it's a custom function that does the same thing that I have posted, including a hard-coded file path.

Comment: @silver light: ...a cut and paste error! :-)  form.save() should handle the image fields.

Comment: thank you! I did not bound the form to a model, but just saving the model itself did the trick.